# Vue.js use slot from children's children

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vue.js, slot

So I have the following example:

Here is my child component. Every other ones of the following components is based upon this.

```
<template>
  <div class="content-box">
    <div class="boxtitlecontainer titleColor">
      <slot name="title">Title</slot>
    </div>
    <div class="insidebox boxColor">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is one of the children.

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <box>
      <div slot="title"><slot name="title">Title</slot></div>
      <slot></slot>
    </box>
  </div>
</template>
```

This component is directly used in my `App.vue`. To use `<slot>`s, the only way i found is this one above.

My question is: **Is there a more elegant way of doing this and to not stack up div-Boxes unnecessary?** I mean, I can do it with no named slots. I guess that the `<slot>` can be showed recursivly like `content -> slot(1st children) -> slot(2nd children)` but i have no idea about how to do it with named slots.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the goal ?

Comment: The goal is already accomplisehd by my solution up there. The question is how can it be more elegant. But to specify, the goal is to reuse the box-component. When i remove the div nothing or the text in the slot is shown.

Comment: It's unclear, you would want `<slot>` as recursive component ?

Comment: I want it to be recursive with named slots. I have accomplished this doing it with no named but I need to do it with named slots.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here but perhaps this can help you out: https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-abstract-components/

Answer (score 0):

instead of depending on slot for passing your content, why not use props instead?

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <box>
      <div v-text="title">Title</div>
      <slot></slot>
    </box>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['title']
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. But it is not possible to use other markup in the slot then. I used a similar approach but it foes not go with my needs.

Comment: what are your needs?

Comment: check out refs, I think that could satisfy your needs